# ANDROID Listview button listener database

Tags: android, listview

If I click the button in listview for 2 or 3 times the first button is the one being applied. For example this is ok, Present -> Absent. If I click Present->Absent->Lat­e if I click the back button rather than Late it would appear Absent.

here's my code.

```
    btncClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase(cPresent)) {
                database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("teachers.db", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                database.execSQL("UPDATE tbl_attendance SET status='Absent' WHERE _studID='" + _Attendance2.getStudID() + "' AND _dateID='" + current + "'");

            } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Absent")) {
                database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("teachers.db", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                database.execSQL("UPDATE tbl_attendance SET status='Late' WHERE _studID='" + _Attendance2.getStudID() + "'AND _dateID='" + current + "'");

            } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Late")) {
                database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("teachers.db", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                database.execSQL("UPDATE tbl_attendance SET status='Excuse' WHERE _studID='" + _Attendance2.getStudID() + "'AND _dateID='" + current + "'");
            } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Excuse")) {
                database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("teachers.db", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                database.execSQL("UPDATE tbl_attendance SET status='Present' WHERE _studID='" + _Attendance2.getStudID() + "'AND _dateID='" + current + "'");
            }
            if (btncClick.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Present")) {
                btncClick.setText("Absent");
            } else if (btncClick.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Absent")) {
                btncClick.setText("Late");
            } else if (btncClick.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Late")) {
                btncClick.setText("Excuse");
            } else if (btncClick.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Excuse")) {
                btncClick.setText("Present");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It does updating the database once after calling the method by clicking a button once but after clicking the button again, it doesnt update the database.

Comment: Post your full adapter code, and explain what *back*, *late*... buttons should do?